# Solar System Orbit html center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my Solar System model, when you click 'Toggle Orbits' it display the orbit for the all familiar planet earth, but you notice that the ring is not centred in the middle of the planet, only outside of it, how would I make it so it would be in the middle?

```js
function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var x = Math.random() * screen.width;
    var y = Math.random() * screen.height;
    var star = document.createElement('div');
    star.className = 'star';
    star.style.left = x + 'px';
    star.style.top = y + 'px';
    document.body.appendChild(star);
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #000;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.star {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: white;
  z-index: -1;
}
.sun {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*box-shadow: rgb(204, 153, 0) 0px 0px 50px 0px;*/
}
#button-change {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
}
.earth {
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: green 0 0 25px;
}
.earth-orbit {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  -webkit-animation: spin-right 15s linear infinite;
}
.earth-lines {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
.moon {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
.moon-orbit {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: -12.5px;
  margin-bottom: -37px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin-right 4s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin-right {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Vanishing Act</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css' />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
        $('.earth-orbit').toggleClass('earth-lines');
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
  <img class="sun" src="5.png">
  </div>
  <div class="earth-orbit">
    <div class='moon-orbit'>
      <img class="moon" src="http://space-facts.com/wp-content/uploads/moon-transparent.png" />
    </div>

    <img class="earth" src="http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=74422923" />
  </div>
  <button id="button-change">Toggle Orbits</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put `.earth-lines` statically on `.earth-orbit`, so adjusting margin of `.earth` and `.moon` is a logical solution.

On the other hand, let's think out of the box. What if we put `.earth-lines` as a separate div? Like this:

```
<div class="earth-lines">
</div>

<div class="earth-orbit ">
    <div class='moon-orbit'>
      <img class="moon" src="http://space-facts.com/wp-content/uploads/moon-transparent.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS for `.earth-lines` would look like this:

```
.earth-lines {
    display: none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 226px;
    width: 226px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -113px;
    margin-top: -113px;
}
```

The last thing would be is to adjust the JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $('.earth-lines').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

In this case, it would be toggled and will look just the way you want it to. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x3ybjd0f/1/

P.S. Marvelous idea and implementation, I love it ;)

**UPDATE**

How to fix the Sun.

In your code you have `<img class="sun" src="5.png">`

According to your comment, the link to the picture is http://toms-storage.tk/5.png

So the right code for this would be `<img class="sun" src="http://toms-storage.tk/5.png">`

Comment: Thanks xD But with my OCD acting up, could you help me with getting the line in the center of the earth and with the orbit lines starting hidden? Oh and do you know why the sun is squashed like that?

Comment: the sun is not seen since a proper URL to the image 5.png does not exist in the code

Comment: @user4191887 I have updated the css code to initially hide the line and to center it to look like it's in the middle of the `.earth`. The sun is not there because the URL for the sun is incorrect - you probably have the file locally.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix the picture?

Comment: @user4191887 I updated my post. And I think you need to review your own code more often to check for mistakes like that one.

Comment: Upvoted for giving a full solution with explanation as opposed to just posting code.

Comment: @Nordenheim Notice it is squashed?

Comment: @user4191887 By gods, mate. Because the original is 512*437

Comment: But in css, it's 100 x 100

Answer (score 3):

```
.earth {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

However, that will throw the Moon off of the orbit. Adjusting the `margin-left` of `.moon-orbit` class will fix that.

Answer (score 3):

in css

```
.moon-orbit{
  margin-bottom : -14px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the change:

```
.moon-orbit {
  top: 50%;
left: 50%;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
margin-left: 6px;
margin-bottom: -37px;
border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin-right 4s linear infinite;
}

.earth {
position: absolute;
height: 25px;
width: 25px;
margin-left: 20px;
border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: green 0 0 25px;
}
```

And here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ehg64ru/1/